# Reading unformatted text data with Fortran (differences with gfortran and intel fortran)

Tags: text, io, segmentation-fault, fortran

I am trying to read data from a very large text file within a FORTRAN program.  The program works fine when compiled with the Intel Fortran compiler, but segfaults when compiled with gfortran.

The data file is formatted such that there is typically six singles on each line.  But every ~10k lines there is a line with less than six values.  For example:

```
0.1466E+01  0.1459E+01  0.1203E+01  0.1362E+01  0.1281E+01  0.1544E+01
0.1480E+01  0.1517E+01  0.1238E+01  0.1056E+01  0.1204E+01  0.1269E+01
                                 :
0.3555E+00  0.3253E+00  0.6127E+00  0.6702E+00  0.1848E+01  0.2122E+01
0.2039E+01  0.6350E+00  0.6725E+00
```

I have written a program in FORTRAN to read this file.  A minimal version looks like this:

```
PROGRAM bigdataread

REAL,ALLOCATABLE :: VAR(:)
INTEGER :: NP, NVAR, NPER
CHARACTER(len=80) :: MOPFILE

       MOPFILE = 'bigdata.OUT'
       NP = 9945            ! Number of grid points
       NVAR = 7             ! Number of Variables
       NPER = 2920      ! Number of times-steps

    ALLOCATE(VAR(NP*NVAR*NPER))
    WRITE(LUNCO,*)'Alocated size ',SIZE(VAR)
    OPEN(UNIT=8,FILE=MOPFILE)    
    READ(8,*,END=104,ERR=101)VAR
    WRITE(*,*)'Bigdata sucsessfully read'

    STOP

104    WRITE(*,*)'Reached end of file'
101    WRITE(*,*)'Problem reading in the .OUT file'

STOP
END
```

If 'NPER' is more 1300, the program (when compiled with gfortran) will segfault.  I have confirmed that the data file has the correct number of values using '$ wc bigdata.OUT'.  Given the dependence on variable size it seems to be a memory issue, but I can't figure out how.  My understanding is that gfortan puts arrays on the heap rather than the stack by default.  Anyone know what is going on here?  Maybe you have some helpful advice for further debugging this problem?

Here are the specifics of my platform:

gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

ifort version 12.1.3

Processor: 12x Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3930K CPU @ 3.20GHz

Memory: 16412MB (8865MB used)

Operating System:  Linux Mint 13 Maya

Comment: There are various recent gfortran segmentation fault bugs listed [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=Segmentation). Is one of these yours?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  As far as I can tell the problem I am experiencing is not in the bug list.

Comment: First, check the returned status of the allocate statement.  Second, take control of reading the data, don't use list-directed input to gulp `var` in one go.  Neither of these steps will, necessarily, fix the problem but one or both ought to help you diagnose the problem more precisely.

Comment: Unformatted text is not a very lucky term for Fortran. Try to use the debugging options the compiler has `-g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all` and possibly also `valgrind` to identify the place the problem is happening.

Comment: @Vladimir: I have used debugging options to identify the segfault as originating from the 'READ' call. Just working on HPM's suggestions now.

Comment: you know you dont declare/set lunco.

Comment: @george:  thanks I had missed that when I cut down the program.  I fixed it now in the original post.  Not the source of the error though.

Comment: @High Performance Mark: Thanks for you comments.  Allocate "STAT" returns 0 as expected.  When read in VAR line-by-line the program finds the 'end of file' at line 33869081. '$ wc -l bigdata.OUT' and the program (compiled with ifort) give the end of file at line 33889520.  I compared the line returned in each case and all are indeed the last time in the file.  The different line numbers suggests that there is some difference in how each program is interpreting newline/line-feed characters.  Any ideas further idea would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: So I would use an editor to cut a slice out of the input file which contains line 33869081 and see if the problem is a strange character at the end of that line which gfortran doesn't like.